# how to trigger validation and get validation result after submit form action in Angular?

Tags: angular, forms, angular2-form-validation

I have this formgroup:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  id: [],
  active: [true],
  name: [''],
});
```

and this submit form function:

```
onSubmit(submitForm: FormGroup) {
  this.submitForm.controls['name'].setValidators([MyValidators.unique(`name`, () => {
     return this.service.checkNameUnique(this.submitForm.value.name, this.labelFg.value.id);
  })]);
}
```

I didn't set validation to the form when initiating because this form will only be validated after I clicked the submit button. So I use the `setValidators`function to set validation in onSubmit function.

But question is: How do I trigger this validation and get the validation result?

Comment: this will help you out https://loiane.com/2017/08/angular-reactive-forms-trigger-validation-on-submit/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclamer** As andrew say, from Angular 8, it's possible use `{updateOn:'submit'}` using formBuilder, appologies for the inconvenience.

You can use the "constructors" of FormGroup and Form controls, <strike>not the formBuilder</strike>), then you can add {updateOn:'submit'}, see the docs: [forms validation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#note-on-performance)

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
  id: new FormControl('',Validators.required),
  active: new FormControl(true,Validators.requiredTrue),
  name: new FormControl('',
        {validators:Validators.required,
         asyncValidators:MyValidators),
},{updateOn:'submit'});
```

Yes, <strike>only can</strike> do it using the constructors of FormGroup, but you can see it's not very diferent to use FormBuilder

**Update** an [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2z2mqr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: When I used update on the field is marked with errors, however in order to get the field to go back I have to click submit again. Does the form no longer have realtime error checking with the updateOn feature?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
  this.submitForm.controls['name'].setValidators([MyValidators.unique(`name`, () => {
     return this.service.checkNameUnique(this.submitForm.value.name, this.labelFg.value.id);
  })]);
this.submitForm.controls["name"].updateValueAndValidity();
```

[angular-setvalidators](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-setvalidators)

**Update**
Check out this [blog](https://alligator.io/angular/async-validators/) to get the best example about angular async-validators

Comment: I used ```setAsyncValidators``` instead. I need to save the form value to database if the form validation result is true. But I just can't get that result

Comment: When you add or remove a (setValidators/setAsyncValidators) validator at run time, you must call updateValueAndValidity() for the new validation to take effect. [setasyncvalidators](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setasyncvalidators)

Comment: It worked! But how do I use ```this.submitForm.get('name').status```? the ```setAsyncValidators ``` is async. I need the validation result right after that

Comment: @Liem - check the updated answer. I hope, 'validateEmailNotTaken' method will help you to achieve what you are trying.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing stopping you using [FormBuilder](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder) API and passing [AbstractControlOptions](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControlOptions). You can pass these options to the controls and/or the group.

```
this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
  id: ['', [Validators.required]],
  name: ['', {validators: ..., asyncValidators: ..., updateOn: ...}],
}, { updateOn: 'submit' });
```

### [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so58387436-formbuilder-onsubmit-example)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Id" formControlName="id" />
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name" formControlName="name" />

      <br/>
      <br/>
    <h3>Value</h3>
      {{ formGroup.value | json }}
    <h3>Valid</h3>
      {{ formGroup.valid | json }}

      <br/>
      <br/>
    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>

  </form>
  `
})
export class AppComponent  {
  formGroup: FormGroup

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
      id: ['', [Validators.required]],
      name: [''],
    }, { updateOn: 'submit' });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log('onSubmit')
    console.log(this.formGroup.value)
    console.log(this.formGroup.valid)
  }
}
```

Comment: good point :). you can use `{updateOn:'blur'}` with FormBuilder too from Angular 8

Comment: questions is: before click submit button or before validation, the form.valid is always false.

Comment: form.valid is always false because until it updates it has value `{ id: "", name: "" }`. I would say this is intended behaviour